# Share code between multiple projects/folders/apps within same repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I have a single repo with multiple projects or apps inside multiple folders with each one having its own package.json file and node_modules. All these projects have a file with same code and its being redundant in each project. I want to fetch it out and make it sharable somehow. 
One way is to use the npm package. Thinking of other ways here. Please elt me know if you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the projects run on the same folder structure, you can simply move a file in the shared parent folder and require it from there.
If you have a DevOps cycle, you could copy that file into each folder in the build step. GitLab CI makes it pretty easy, but it can be done in Git without much struggle.
The npm package, however, seems like the most long-term stable and convenient solution, if the codebase is not proprietary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external module for this single file (perhabs in the futur you will have more files to share between yours projects)

- Initialise a new project for this single file

`mkdir my-external-lib ; cd my-external-lib
npm init`

You will need to edit the `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "my-external-lib",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Library function to all my project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "<url-path-or-your-external-library>"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "<you>",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {},
    "homepage": "<url-path-or-your-external-library>#readme",
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

**You are not forgiven to make your project public in github**

The problem of this solution, is that you need to `rm -rf node_modules; npm i` each time you update your external package. I don't know why `npm update` doesn't work.